# Methods for multiplication of large matrices

Tags: matrices

Say we are given a $4\times 4$ matrix $A$. Is there an easy method to finding $A^2$, $A^3$, $A^4$ and so on?
I know that for the long way around this we can just follow the multiplication formula (for a $2\times 2$ matrix):
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        a^2+bc & ab+bd\\
        ca+bd & cb+d^2\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
And then times that with the original matrix for $A^3$ and so on. But obviously, following this method for larger matrices is simply time consuming. So is there a simplified method to solve such questions?

Comment: Characteristic Polynomial can be used to greatly simplify this computation.

Comment: your matrix is similar to its Jordan form.

Comment: If it is daigonalizable (not all matrices are diagonalizable) then $A = P D P^{-1}$ and $A^n = P D^n P^{-1}.$  In the tradition of the best, I don't have enough room here to detail the procedure.

Comment: You may quickly find matrix powers of a symmetric matrices using the Schur factorization. For large unsymmetric matrices nothing can be done except reusing previously computed powers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A square real-valued matrix, $A$, will satisfy its own characteristic polynomial. This is the content of the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem

This provides an efficient method for computing powers of the matrix $A$ (especially higher powers).

Comment: That is indeed a good method, however you do need the lower powers of the matrix to begin with, so for a 4 by 4 matrix, the Char equation is of 4th degree and thus the lower powers of $A$ are needed.

Comment: @imranfat: True, but I suspect that, once you have the characteristic polynomial, you can create simpler expressions for the lower powers through some clever manipulations (still probably have to do at least A^2 the 'hard' way; or an equivalent amount of work)